# ¿Cómo validar captcha y datos del formulario utilizando solo PHP?

Tags: php, html5

> Estoy desarrollando un formulario de contacto en la misma página y ocultando el formulario al enviar con **PHP** pero tengo problemas en validar la **imagen captcha** al presionar el botón en enviar me muestra los dos mensajes juntos al enviar:

- Los caracteres no coincide con el código captcha.
- Gracias por sus comentarios.

Por medio de este código obtengo los valores del captcha de la imagen.

`if($_SESSION['vcode'] != $_POST['vcode']) {}`

Debido al problema de validar el captcha tengo la duda de dónde incluir la validación de los datos del formulario con **PHP.**

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Formulario de **contacto.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Formulario de Contacto</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Función para validar contra cualquier intento de inyección de correo electrónico
function IsInjected($str) {
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
?>
<?php
session_start();
$errors = '';
$nombre = '';
$email = '';
$telefono = '';
$mensaje = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  if($_SESSION['vcode'] != $_POST['vcode']) {
    $errors .= "Los caracteres no coincide con el código captcha";
  }

  $nombre = $_POST["name"];
  $email    = $_POST["mail"];
  $telefono = $_POST["phone"];
  $mensaje  = $_POST["message"];

  if(empty($nombre)) {
    $errors .= "\n Por favor ingresar su nombre. "; 
  }
  if(empty($email)) {
    $errors .= "\n Por favor ingresar su email. "; 
  }elseif (IsInjected($email)) {
    $errors .= "\n email no valido. ";
  }
  if(empty($telefono)) {
    $errors .= "\n Por favor ingresar su numero telefono. "; 
  }
  if($_POST['producto'] == 0){
     $errors .= "\n Debe seleccionar un producto";
  }
  if(empty($mensaje)) {
    $errors .= "\n Por favor ingresar su mensaje. "; 
  }
  if(empty($errors)) {
    $asunto = "";
    $message = "Usuario:".$_POST['name']." Email:".$_POST['mail']." Telefono ".$_POST['phone']." Informacion ".$_POST['message'];
    $destino = "contacto@example.com";
    $remitente = "From: contacto@example.com";
    mail($destino,$asunto,$message,$remitente);
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    echo "Gracias por sus comentarios";
  }
}else{
?>

<div class="error">
<?php
if(!empty($errors)){
  echo "<p class='err'>".nl2br($errors)."</p>";
}
?>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="touch">
    <div class="name">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre" value='<?php echo htmlentities($nombre) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <input type="text" name="mail"  placeholder="Email" value='<?php echo htmlentities($email) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="phone">
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value='<?php echo htmlentities($telefono) ?>'>
    </div>
    <div class="select-pro">
      <select name="producto">
        <option value="0" selected>Asunto...</option>
        <option value="1">Producto 1</option>
        <option value="2">Producto 2<option>
        <option value="3">Producto 3</option>
        <option value="4">Otro</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="Customer-message">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Su consulta..."><?php echo htmlentities($mensaje) ?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="capcha">
      <img src="image.php" name="vcode" id="phoca-captcha"/>
      <input name="vcode" type="text" placeholder="Codigo captcha">
    </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
  </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

> Lo deseado es ocultar el formulario al enviar y mostrar el siguiente mensaje ***Gracias por sus comentarios*** pero al enviar ya sea en blanco o los campos llenados correctamente o incorrectamente se oculta el formulario adicional a ello se pierde la validación de los campos debido a que no muestra ningún mensaje de error.

Otro error es la función para validar contra cualquier intento de inyección de correo electrónico, al ingresar un email no válido ejemplo(falso@aasadw) no muestra el mensaje de error: **email no válido.**

Para evitar que el usuario pierda la información dada en los campos del formulario al no escribir correctamente los caracteres del código captcha añadí a cada campo esta acción:

`value='<?php echo htmlentities($nombre) ?>'`

Pero en el `select -> option` cómo evito que se pierda la selección del producto al enviar.

Comment: en donde se envian esos codigos expliqueme

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Antes de continuar analiza, estudia y practica en **w3schools**
en [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp)
encontraras una guia completa con ejemplos sencillos y prácticos te ayudará mucho.

> **TEMA DE SEGURIDAD** en el tratamiento de los formularios PHP!
>
> Una correcta validación de los datos es importante para proteger los formularios de hackers y spammers!

Preocuparse por la seguridad de los formularios es fundamental para evitar ataques de Cross Site Scripting (XSS) que ejecutan comandos que puede redirigir al usuario a un archivo en otro servidor, y ese archivo puede contener código malicioso que puede alterar las variables globales o enviar el formulario a otra dirección para guardar los datos de usuario.

Por lo tanto es importante lo que has realizado pero vale recalcar para satisfacer las dudas que puedan presentar otros usuarios.

**Vulnerable** (Esta acción puede ser utilizado por los hackers!) ataques de Cross Site Scripting (XSS).

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
```

**Formulario de acción segura** `htmlspecialchars` (Importante lo que has implementado en tu formulario).

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Cualquier manipulación de un ataque de un Hackers:

```
http://www.example.com/test_form.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E
```

Con la función `htmlspecialchars ()` convierte los caracteres especiales a entidades HTML. Ahora bien, si el usuario intenta explotar la variable `PHP_SELF`, el resultado será el siguiente resultado:

```
<form method="post" action="test_form.php/&quot;&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert('hacked')&lt;/script&gt;">
```

Ahora bien sin la función `htmlspecialchars ()` el resultado sería diferente a un ataque inofensivo como ejemplo.

```
<form method="post" action="test_form.php/"><script>alert('hacked')</script>
```

Podrías añadir una función y otro parámetro para mejorar aún más la seguridad de esta manera:

```
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $nombre = test($_POST["name"]);
    $email    = test($_POST["mail"]);
    $telefono = test($_POST["phone"]);
    $mensaje  = test($_POST["message"]);
  }

  function test($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }
```

**Validar Correo electrónico**

La forma más fácil y más seguro para comprobar si está bien formado una dirección de correo electrónico es utilizar la función de PHP `filter_var ()`.

```
  if(empty($email)) {
    $errors .= "\n Por favor ingrese su email. "; 
  }else{
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $errors .="\n email no válido";
    }
  }
```

También puedes **validar Nombre** de esta forma sencilla para comprobar si el campo del nombre sólo contiene letras y espacios en blanco.

```
  if(empty($nombre)) {
    $errors .= "\n Por favor ingrese su nombre."; 
  }else {
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nombre)) {
      $errors .= "\n Sólo se permiten letras y espacios en blanco.";
    }
  }
```

**Validar número de teléfono**

> **Nota:** Existen diferentes formas y parámetros para validar número de teléfono a un país específico.

En esta validación se acepta los números de 10 dígitos en adelante de todos los países incluyendo código de país en su validación ejemplo: +1 xxx xxx xxx.

```
  if(empty($telefono)) {
    $errors .= "\n Por favor ingrese su número de telefónico. "; 
  }else{
    if(!preg_match("/^\+?\d{1,3}?[- .]?\(?(?:\d{2,3})\)?[- .]?\d\d\d[- .]?\d\d\d\d$/", $telefono)) {
      $errors .="\n Número de teléfono no válido";
    }
  }
```

Si deseas optar por un número de teléfono específico debes cambiar esto:

```
^\+?\d{1,3}?[- .]?\(?(?:\d{2,3})\)?[- .]?\d\d\d[- .]?\d\d\d\d$
```

por lo deseado.

Sobre ocultar el formulario de contacto al enviar, debes cambiar el mensaje por una variable.

Cambia esto:

```
echo "Gracias por sus comentarios";
```

por esto:

```
$msg= "Gracias por sus comentarios";
```

Reemplaza esto:

```
<div class="error">
<?php
if(!empty($errors)){
  echo "<p class='err'>".nl2br($errors)."</p>";
}
?>
</div>
```

Por esto:

```
<div class="error">
<?php 

if(isset($msg)){
  echo "<p class='err'>".$msg."</p>";
}else{
  if (isset($errors))
    echo "<p class='err'>".nl2br($errors)."</p>";
?>
</div>
 # formulario
<form></form>
 # Al final del formulario cerrar
<?php } ?>
```

Para evitar que se pierda la selección del producto de las opciones añade este parámetro donde se encuentra el resto de los datos `$telefono, $nombre`

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $seleccionado = test($_POST['producto']);
}
```

Ahora para evitar errores añade también la siguiente variable `$seleccionado = '';` por encima del `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Reemplaza el `select` simple **HTML**.

```
  <select name="producto">
    <option value="0" selected>Asunto...</option>
    <option value="1">Producto 1</option>
    <option value="2">Producto 2<option>
    <option value="3">Producto 3</option>
    <option value="4">Otro</option>
  </select>
```

Por un select dinamico con **PHP.** (*Con esto no se perderán los datos seleccionados*)

```
  <select name="producto">
  <?php
     $datos = array("Asunto","TV","Internet");
     for($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++) {
        if($i==$seleccionado) {
           echo "<option value='".$i."' selected>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
        }else {
           echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$datos[$i]."</option>";
        }
     }
  ?>
  </select>
```

Comment: perfecto funciona, genial las recomendaciones. Pero como evitó que se pierda la selección al enviar al existir errores conservó los otros datos pero la selección se borra?

Comment: +1 compadre! buena respuesta

Comment: Hola @Josues acabo de editar mi respuesta, edita tu pregunta para que sea clara a un solo problema sin tantas incógnitas en ella vale saludos :)

Comment: Gracias @sioesi :) espero sea muy útil a futuro para los demás que puedan presentar un problema similar saludos :)

Answer (score 2):

Lo importante es saber, el captcha aparece cuando el usuario intenta cierta cantidad de veces enviar el formulario o siempre esta?

Si siempre esta entonces es un campo mas de tu formulario, y el codigo lo dejaria tal cual lo tienes, salvo que crearia una variable flag `$error` y `$mensaje` ademas de agregar `name` a tu selector

```
<select name="producto">
    <option value="0" selected>Asunto...</option>
    <option value="1">Producto 1</option>
    <option value="2">Producto 2<option>
    <option value="3">Producto 3</option>
    <option value="4">Otro</option>
</select>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
$error = false;
$mensaje = "";
if($_SESSION['vcode'] != $_POST['vcode']) {
    $mensaje+= "Los caracteres no coincide con el código captcha";
    $error = true;
}
if($_POST['producto'] == 0){
     $mensaje+= "Debe seleccionar un producto";
     $error = true;
}
if($error){
     echo $mensaje;
}else { 
     $asunto = "";
     $message = "Usuario:".$_POST['name']." Email:".$_POST['email']." Telefono ".$_POST['phone']." Informacion ".$_POST['message'];
     $destino = "contacto@example.com";
     $remitente = "From: contacto@example.com";

     mail($destino,$asunto,$message,$remitente);
     unset($_POST['submit']);
     echo "Gracias por sus comentarios";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50287/discussion-on-answer-by-sioesi-como-validar-captcha-y-datos-del-formulario-util).